# Weird internet problem

Tags: networking, firefox, internet, http-proxy

I am using Debian 8.5, with dnsmasq. I am having a very weird internet access problem which I couldn't understand why.

I have a pretty stupid internet provider (turktelekom) and when you exceed bandwith they redirect you to an error page normally, but then it goes away after you enter other websites.

But there is a new problem today. Here is some diagnostics:

Enter in Firefox for example, `example.com`, it redirects you to:

http://bilgi.turktelekom.com.tr/adilkullanimuygulamasi/index.aspx?fid=1

Enter, `example.com/X` (or any other path) then you get the `example.com` website.

The same is true for many other websites, except google.

I tried with different browsers, cleared all cache, reinstalled browsers, restart networking, reboot, stop dnsmasq totally, and I tried everything I can think of.

In Firefox, in developer tools, it shows HTTP 307, and then redirects to that silly address.

The weird thing is this:
When I get any website using `wget` or `curl` there is no problem.

When I enter any website with my Android phone, connected to the wireless router, again there is no problem.

I tried with Firefox, Opera, Chrome, it is the same.

I tried,

```
dig anywebsite.com
```

it correctly shows the IP. When I enter the IP into a browser, again I am redirected to that silly address.

When I enter a https address, it doesn't redirect to that silly address. This occurs only for http addresses.

Do the given diagnostics makes any sense to anybody?

**SOLVED**

In case anybody else have the same problem:

These abusers interfere your traffic and inspect user-agents and other data. Probably because of a bug in their system, it redirects to a non-existent address. If you change the user-agent of your browser the problem goes away. For example in Firefox you can do this:

Write `about:config` in the address bar. Accept the warning message. Right click an empty place and select `New > String`, then write `general.useragent.override` and leave the second dialog empty (or write a random user-agent).

Comment: I agree, it's a very strage situation. Only a tip: have you tried to change the useragent of browser to wget or curl? It seems they're using transparent proxy on port 80, which can use any tricky (stupid) configuration.

Comment: or vice-versa. Or try firefox with a totally new profile - just to be sure there no cached objects.
The solution can be to bypass this transparent proxy. This can be done via a custom proxy (google for it), a vpn connection (pay for it), or try hola extensions: http://www.hola.org/

Comment: vpn can solve your problem if you route your tcp port 80 traffic via it. (except if it is also behind of this stupid isp) I think hola will also solve this problem. It's a bit slow, but you can specify which sites do you wanna reach via hola.

Answer (score 1):

Try to change the useragent of browser to fool the stupid transparent proxy.
Here it is a detailed howto for the famous browsers: http://www.howtogeek.com/113439/how-to-change-your-browsers-user-agent-without-installing-any-extensions/